# My site does not open, stays on the white screen, raises "Object doesn't support property or method 'validator'" error

Tags: javascript

That's error ; [image]When I followed the console screen while the page was loading it gave the error "SCRIPT438: SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'validator'". It is showing the error in the contact.js file.
I could not solve the problem. Can you help me ?

My code in contact.js :

```
$(function () {
    $('.contact-form').validator();
    
    $('.contact-form').on('submit', function (e) {
        if (!e.isDefaultPrevented()) {
            var url = "vendor/contact/contact.php";

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: url,
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                success: function (data)
                {
                    var messageAlert = 'alert-' + data.type;
                    var messageText = data.message;

                    var alertBox = '<div class="alert ' + messageAlert + ' alert-dismissable">' + messageText + '</div>';
                    if (messageAlert && messageText) {
                        $('.contact-form').find('.messages').html(alertBox);
                        $('.contact-form')[0].reset();
                    }
                }
            });
            return false;
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: I'm going to say the problem is you aren't including `validator` script anywhere in the code.

Comment: It is unlikely that we can help you without a [mcve].

Comment: Or it’s not loading before your script runs. Make sure you’re including the validator script then also wrap it in ‘document.ready’ or ‘DOMContentLoaded’ hooks.

Comment: A dollar sign usually represents the jQuery library. So it looks like you're trying to use jQuery with a validation plugin. Make sure that you include the validation plugin via a script tag or some other method. Otherwise "validator" won't exist. If you're using this library: https://github.com/jquery-validation/jquery-validation, then you might need to use the word "validate" instead of "validator".

Comment: As a side note, be careful about concatenating "messageText" into html as you are doing there. If the data comes from a user, that user can inject code into the page. It's only okay if "messageText" is highly controlled text that can't be edited by users at all.

Answer (score 0):

There's no such method called 'validator'.

Assuming you're using the typical jquery validator plugin, what you're looking for is just 'validate()'